# CLASSPATH seems to be ignored by openJDK8 on RaspiOS Lite Buster

Tags: java

I installed openJDK8 on a Raspberry Pi 0H with RaspiOS Lite (BUSTER).  I also installed wiringpi and pi4j libraries.  I added the directories to CLASSPATH in the /etc/environment file and even tried to export it, but java & javac seem to ignore the variable.  I have to specify the classpath every time I compile or run my code.  GOOGLE does not show any info on it, every mention I found was to use -cp.

Is there no way to specify a CLASSPATH variable for openJDK8?

Comment: Why not export it from /home/pi/.bashrc?

Comment: Two things; add the contents of /etc/environment to your post, and double check the value is what you think it is by including the output of echo $CLASSPATH

Comment: There's not enough information here to rule out errors by the OP, hence "non-reproducible" at this point.

Answer (score 2):

[`/etc/environment`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/environment.d.5.html) is not yet another startup script, it's a configuration file. As a result, "exporting" variables in it is simply a syntax error (see the man page for the correct syntax), and the applicability of any settings there to your session depends on PAM/`systemd` configuration. If your `java` process is not ultimately started by a `systemd --user` instance or a process which uses PAM, it will never see those variables you set in `/etc/environment`.

Unless there is a good reason to set CLASSPATH in a different place, I would set it directly in the command you use to run Java (`java -cp path1;path2`)

Comment: This is a little bit contra `man 5 environment` and [this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473035/25985); by that, `/etc/environment` is used by PAM -- ie. `login`, which is used in the background by display managers (that present GUI logins) *[or not see further comments]*, meaning those variables should be set for every user which logs in, and has no direct relationship to systemd, whose conf files are in `/etc/systemd/`.

Comment: @goldilocks Interesting. When I run `man 5 environment` on the Pi, I get "Configuration files in the environment.d/ directories contain lists of
       environment variable assignments for services started by the systemd
       user instance.  systemd-environment-d-generator(8) parses them and
       updates the environment exported by the systemd user instance." Furthermore, my GUI session is started by `lightdm.service`, I think `login` is only involved in console sessions, which are in turn started by `getty@ttyXXX.service` instances.

Comment: Huh -- are you sure that isn't [man 5 environment.d](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/environment.d.5.html) (<- note the `.d` suffix)?  What comes up for `man 5 environment` on RpiOS buster (I haven't upgraded to bullseye, but it is the same on fedora 34 x86-64, which has to be as up-to-date as it gets systemd wise) is (I just noticed this) the same page as for `man pam_env.conf`.   The `environment.d` page just notes that there is a symlink *to /etc/environment* for backward compatibility.   `lighdm` is a display manager (dm), but my statement about them from the first comment is...

Comment: ...I think incorrect (now, at least); they don't apply `login`, although it looks like they still use PAM (but I did not check lightdm specifically).  In any case, pretty sure I'm still right that what this means is `/etc/environment` should apply no matter how the user session was instantiated, since either PAM or the systemd mechanism is used.

Comment: There actually is no `/etc/environmnet.d` (.d) directory on RpiOS (or the fedora box I'm on), but there is a symlink to `/etc/enviroment` (which exists but is empty) in `/usr/lib/environment.d`, and it is applied via ssh login (which uses PAM). I don't have a default desktop Pi convenient to check WRT lightdm.  I'd guess the problem here is what you point out about the use of `export` -- but it is plain incorrect to say that "/etc/environment is ... a configuration file of systemd".  **It isn't.** Though it may be sourced for "backward compatibility", PAM is still in use and it's part of PAM.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the clarification! My point was mostly that it's a configuration file rather than a shell script, so shell script format will not work in this file.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule it's a bad idea to set the classpath at the user or OS level.

You better set it up during build using Ant, Maven, or Gradle. At runtime you can set it on the startup BASH/SH script.

Why? Because different applications may want to use different libraries. Maybe even different versions of the same library. If you set it at the user level, then one app may end up running the correct version of the library, but another will run (and inexplicable crash) since it's running the wrong one for itself.